# Multiprocessing Not Keeping Results

Tags: python, class, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I tried to run the following multiprocessing code:

```
import multiprocessing

class test(multiprocessing.Process):
    def __init__(self, name):
        multiprocessing.Process.__init__(self)
        self.name = name
        self.finished = False

    def run(self):
        print("executed")
        self.finished = True

test_list = []
test_list.append(test('first'))
test_list.append(test('second'))

for t in test_list:
    t.start()

for t in test_list:
    t.join()

for t in test_list:
    print(t.finished)
```

and get the results:

```
executed
executed
False
False
```

The `False` outputs seem strange. I have set the attribute `finished` to be `True` in the method `run`, and the outputs `executed` show that the `run` method has been executed. And, if I add a line `print(self.finished)` immediately after `self.finished=True` in the method `run`, the output would be `True`. Why does the class attribute `finished` change after multiprocessing has finished?

Thanks!

Comment: t.finish is updated in other process, not in main process.  See: https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#sharing-state-between-processes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will allow you to share the finished value between processes.  It uses a `multiprocessing.Value` to create a shared object using shared memory.

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Value

class test(Process):
    def __init__(self, name, fin):
        Process.__init__(self)
        self.name = name
        self.finished = fin

    def run(self):
        print("executed")
        self.finished.value = True

test_list = []
test_list.append(test('first', Value('b', False)))
test_list.append(test('second', Value('b', False)))

for t in test_list:
    t.start()

for t in test_list:
    t.join()

for t in test_list:
    print(bool(t.finished.value))
```

Answer (score 1):

The `self.finished = True` executes in another process and only changes the variable in that process, but you are printing the value from the main process.  You need variables that are shared.

```
from multiprocessing import Process,Value
from ctypes import c_bool

class test(Process):
    def __init__(self,name):
        super().__init__()
        self.name = name
        self._finished = Value(c_bool,False)

    def run(self):
        print(self.name,'executed')
        self._finished.value = True

    @property
    def finished(self):
        return self._finished.value

if __name__ == '__main__':
    test_list = [test('first'),
                 test('second')]

    for t in test_list:
        t.start()

    for t in test_list:
        t.join()

    for t in test_list:
        print(t.finished)
```